# How to get publish to wait on AAR file to exist before trying to publish?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

**Problem Statment**
I am trying to create a build and publish a library based on properties I pass in through command line. I would like to use :

```
 ./gradlew clean build publish -PnexusUsername=* -PnexusPassword=* -PmajorVersion=x -PminorVersion=x -PbuildNumber=x
```

**Work Around**
My current work around for this is I use

```
./gradlew clean; ./gradlew build; ./gradlew publish -PnexusUsername=* -PnexusPassword=* -PmajorVersion=x -PminorVersion=x -PbuildNumber=x
```

Below you will find my main build gradle. I have tried many ideas of waiting for assembleRelease to be added and publishing being finalized by it, but alas I am not a gradle expert, so I am asking for help. I have two POJO/POKO libraries and one Android Library that I am publishing out as an AAR. The error I receive is that the POM file cannot be made because the AAR does not exist.

````
import CiCdDependencies.BOSS_SDK_SNAPSHOT
import CiCdDependencies.buildNumber
import CiCdDependencies.majorVersion
import CiCdDependencies.minorVersion
import CiCdDependencies.nexusPassword
import CiCdDependencies.NEXUS_URL
import CiCdDependencies.nexusUserName
import CiCdDependencies.productVersion
import CiCdDependencies.VERSION_NAME
import Coverage.androidCoverage
import Coverage.testCoverage

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0")
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3")
    }
}
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.sonarqube").version("3.3")
}


ext {
    // Major / Minor / Release and Build numbering
    productVersion = (project.findProperty("productVersion") ?: (System.getenv("PRODUCT_VERSION")
        ?: "0")).toString()
    majorVersion =
        (project.findProperty("majorVersion") ?: (System.getenv("MAJOR_VERSION") ?: "0")).toString()
    minorVersion =
        (project.findProperty("minorVersion") ?: (System.getenv("MINOR_VERSION") ?: "0")).toString()
    buildNumber =
        (project.findProperty("buildNumber") ?: (System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "0")).toString()
    //for publishing
    nexusUserName =
        (project.findProperty("nexusUsername") ?: (System.getenv("NEXUS_USERNAME"))).toString()
    nexusPassword =
        (project.findProperty("nexusPassword") ?: (System.getenv("NEXUS_PASSWORD"))).toString()

    testCoverage = project.hasProperty("TEST_COVERAGE")
    androidCoverage = project.hasProperty("ANDROID_COVERAGE")
}

description = "MAFIA BOSS SDK (Kotlin)"

allprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("jacoco")
    }
    // Read only repositories for dependencies; this should never be used to publish
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "DI2E-BossSdkReleases"
            setUrl("$NEXUS_URL$BOSS_SDK_RELEASES")
            credentials {
                username = nexusUserName
                password = nexusPassword
            }
        }
        maven {
            name = "DI2E-BossSdkSnapshots"
            setUrl("$NEXUS_URL$BOSS_SDK_SNAPSHOT")
            credentials {
                username = nexusUserName
                password = nexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        val gitBranch = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".runCommand()

        property("sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8")
        property("sonar.host.url", "https://sonarqube.di2e.net")
        property("sonar.projectVersion", gitBranch)
        property("sonar.projectKey", "MAFIA-KotlinSDK")
        property("sonar.login", "c58feafd2a81797dec0361dd2d8758885e4145d7")
        property("sonar.junit.reportPaths", "**/test-results/**/*.xml")
        property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "**/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/jacocoTestReport.xml")
    }
}

tasks.getByName("publish").dependsOn("build")

/**
 * Publishing configuration
 */
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        logger.lifecycle("Publishing ${VERSION_NAME()}")
        publications {
            val isSnapshot = !project.hasProperty("RELEASE")
            create<MavenPublication>("BOSSSDKJAVA") {
                groupId = "BOSS"
                artifactId = "SDK-KOTLIN"

                version = if (isSnapshot) {
                    "${VERSION_NAME()}-SNAPSHOT"
                } else {
                    VERSION_NAME()
                }
                // The interfaces JAR
                artifact("${rootProject.projectDir}/InfrastructureBase/build/libs/InfrastructureBase.jar") {
                    classifier = "InfrastructureBase"
                }

                // The implementations JAR
                artifact("${rootProject.projectDir}/InfrastructureImpl/build/libs/InfrastructureImpl.jar") {
                    classifier = "InfrastructureImpl"
                }
            }

            create<MavenPublication>("BOSSSDKANDROID") {
                groupId = "BOSS"
                artifactId = "SDK-ANDROID"

                version = if (isSnapshot) {
                    "${VERSION_NAME()}-SNAPSHOT"
                } else {
                    VERSION_NAME()
                }
                // The implementations AAR
                artifact("${rootProject.projectDir}/InfrastructureAndroidImpl/build/outputs/aar/InfrastructureAndroidImpl-release.aar") {
                    classifier = "InfrastructureAndroidImpl"
                }
            }
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url = if (isSnapshot) {
                        logger.lifecycle("Performing snapshot build.")
                        uri("$NEXUS_URL$BOSS_SDK_SNAPSHOT")
                    } else {
                        logger.lifecycle("Performing release build.")
                        uri("$NEXUS_URL$BOSS_SDK_RELEASES")
                    }

                    credentials {
                        username = nexusUserName
                        password = nexusPassword
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName("jacocoTestReport", type = JacocoReport::class) {
        reports {
            print("I am reporting" )
            xml.required.set(testCoverage)
            html.required.set(testCoverage)
        }

        val fileFilter = mutableSetOf(
            "**/R.class",
            "**/R\$*.class",
            "**/BuildConfig.*",
            "**/Manifest*.*",
            "**/*Test*.*",
            "android/**/*.*",
            "**/*\$Lambda$*.*", // Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
            "**/*\$inlined$*.*" // Kotlin specific, Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
        )

        val debugTree = fileTree("${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug") {
            exclude(fileFilter)
        }
        val mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

        sourceDirectories.from(files(mainSrc))
        classDirectories.setFrom(debugTree)

        if (androidCoverage) {
            executionData.setFrom(fileTree("$buildDir") {
                include(
                    setOf(
                        "jacoco/*.exec",
                        "outputs/code-coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*coverage.ec",
                        "outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/*.exec"
                    )
                )
            })
        } else if (testCoverage) {
            executionData.setFrom(fileTree("$buildDir") {
                include(
                    setOf(
                        "jacoco/*.exec",
                        "outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/*.exec"
                    )
                )
            })
        }

        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                eachDependency {
                    if ("org.jacoco" == requested.group) {
                        useVersion("0.8.7")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.getByName("sonarqube"){
    dependsOn(tasks.getByName("jacocoTestReport"))
}

fun String.runCommand(currentWorkingDir: File = file("./")): String {
    val byteOut = getByteOutput()

    project.exec {
        workingDir = currentWorkingDir
        commandLine = this@runCommand.split("\\s".toRegex())
        standardOutput = byteOut
    }
    return String(byteOut.toByteArray()).trim()
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I believe AGP has done something to make it easier, check it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin

```
release(MavenPublication) {
    // Applies the component for the release build variant.
    from components.release

    // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
    groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
    artifactId = 'final'
    version = '1.0'
}
```

> The Android Gradle plugin creates a component for each build variant artifact in your app or library module that you can use to customize a publication to a Maven repository.

And you may need to move the android part to that android library's build.gradle(.kts).